# Add prefix, and suffix to all files in a folder based on user input using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm new in powershell. I am trying to add a prefix, and suffix to all files in a folder.

Currently, this is the script that i have:

```
$RootFolder = Get-Location

Get-ChildItem -Path "$RootFolder\images" |

rename-item –Newname {'PrefixID{0}SuffixDate' -f $_.BaseName + $_.extension }
```

The script above works fine, and it will add a "declared" (e.g: PrefixID_filename_SuffixDate) prefix, and suffix to all files in the folder of \images.

However, I would like to prompt the users to input their desired prefix, and suffix.

I would greatly appreciate any help that i can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to prompt for input using `Read-Host`:

```
$RootFolder = Get-Location

$prefix  = Read-Host "Please enter the Prefix for all files in the 'images' folder"
$postfix = Read-Host "Please enter the Postfix for all files in the 'images' folder (usually a date)"

Get-ChildItem -Path "$RootFolder\images" -File | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Rename-Item –Newname ('{0}_{1}_{2}{3}' -f $prefix, $_.BaseName, $postfix, $_.Extension)
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, it does exactly what i'm aiming to do.

Comment: Btw, how do i prompt user to just add a suffix?

Comment: Ahh, i got it now. I realized that i can just input blank on the first prompt, and just remove the underscores in the array {0}_{1}_{2}{3}